# Why I have to re-install tidyverse or any other package whenever i open new project in r studio?

Tags: tidyverse, rstudio

[image: this error is showing in my new project]

I already install tidyverse pkg in my existing project but when I open new session of project and then called library(tidyverse) I got an error why?

What should I do now?

Comment: That's because you are using `renv()`, which means either `tidyverse` is installed project-wise every time (as opposed to being installed system-wise), or `renv` does not pick up system packages

Answer (score 0):

Are you initially downloading it with "install.packages('tidyverse')" rather than "require(tidyverse)"? The former downloads it whereas the latter temporarily accesses it. If you are installing it, make sure you are not deleting anything from the R library file on your computer.